# Change TextView inside Fragment gives me NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I'm trying to change a  Textview's text inside a fragment, but it gaves me a NullPointerException at the setName method.

I have already tried 2 ways to do this:

```
public class MemberFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView tvName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member,container, false); 

    tvName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);

    return view;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    tvName.setText(name);
}
```

or:

```
public class MemberFragment extends Fragment {
private static TextView tvName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member,container, false); 

    return view;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    tvName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
    tvName.setText(name);
}
```

but none gave me success. Here is where I instantiate the fragment:

```
MemberFragment fragment = new MemberFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();

fragment.setName(map.get(Tags.NAME));
```

and the fragment_member.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/ActionBar.Transparent.MyStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="446dp" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:text="Large Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view in your onCreateView method is the rootView of your fragment.
So just add the following code in your onCreateView method to change the text of your TextView:

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName)).setText("Your new text");
```

Comment: it works, but since the text string is on the MainActivity, how I can change the text there? Should I pass the texts on the fragment constructor?

Comment: Yes, I would pass the text to the fragment. All UI changes should be done there. So put your params in a bundle and add them to your fragment.

In your activity:
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("your_text",value);    
Fragment newFragment = new Fragment ();
newFragment.setArguments(args);

Get params in Fragment:
Bundle b = getArguments();
String yourText = b.getString("your_text");

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
```

instead of :

```
 tvName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
```

Comment: it's still causing NullPointerException :/